# Ghost space between inline-block elements in Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the ghost space between inline-block elements?

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hFDcV/ where you can clearly see a horizontal space between the divs.

And the StackOverflow mandated example code:

```
<div id='row'>
  <div class='box'>Something</div>
  <div class='box'>Something</div>
  <div class='box'>Something</div>
  <div class='box'>Something</div>
</div>

#row {
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

​

Comment: The white-space is rendering between these elements. I'm sure there's a clean way to resolve this, but I'd have to do some testing to figure that out.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: add `float: left;` to `.box` class

Answer (score 4):

One solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hFDcV/4/

Set the font-size of the parent container to `0` and reset it on the child elements.

```
#row {
    font-size:0;
}

.box {
    font-size:12pt;
}
```

Another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hFDcV/10/

You can float the `box` elements left. Setting `overflow:hidden;` on the `row` will prevent it from collapsing to `0` height.

```
#row {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.box {
    float:left;
}
```

There are other solutions in the fantastic article on this problem shared by @RickCalder: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Setting font-size to 0 works. Getting rid of the spaces does as well. http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @stuartrexking Yes, that is actually how I discovered the problem, but it's generally undesirable to muck up the HTML in such a manner.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to achieve this is to insert commentary between inline-block elements!

like this :

```
<div id='row'>
  <div class='box'>Something</div><!--
  --><div class='box'>Something</div><!--
  --><div class='box'>Something</div><!--
  --><div class='box'>Something</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I don't like this kind of code, I think it's ugly.

Comment: I agree, but I really don't want to write comments for function. I think it is a bug of chrome.